# error gem install debugger -v '1.6.8'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems

I'm trying to bundle update and bundle install but I when I `gem install debugger -v '1.6.8'` I get an error installing debugger: error: failed to build gem native extension. It also says that `make failed, exit code 2` and `Gem files will remain installed in ....`

I have ruby 1.9.3p551 and I gem installed rails 3.2.19. I am on Windows.

I already tried `bundle update debugger` and the `gem update debugger-ruby_core_source`, but both are up to date. Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

When I run `bundle update debugger`:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    e:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150525-6232-uw5n6t.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... yes
checking for vm_core.h... yes
checking for iseq.h... yes
checking for insns.inc... yes
checking for insns_info.inc... yes
checking for eval_intern.h... yes
checking for struct iseq_line_info_entry in vm_core.h,iseq.h... no
checking for struct iseq_insn_info_entry in vm_core.h,iseq.h... yes
checking for if rb_iseq_compile_with_option was added an argument filepath... yes creating Makefile

make  clean
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in e:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/debugger-1.6.8 for inspection.
Results logged to e:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/debugger-1.6.8/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.8'` succeeds before bundling.`
```

When I run `gem install debugger -v '1.6.8'`:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing debugger:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    e:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150525-1772-grdsdf.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... yes
checking for vm_core.h... yes
checking for iseq.h... yes
checking for insns.inc... yes
checking for insns_info.inc... yes
checking for eval_intern.h... yes
checking for struct iseq_line_info_entry in vm_core.h,iseq.h... no
checking for struct iseq_insn_info_entry in vm_core.h,iseq.h... yes
checking for if rb_iseq_compile_with_option was added an argument filepath... yes
creating Makefile

make  clean
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in    e:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/debugger-1.6.8 for inspection.
Results logged to e:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/debugger-1.6.8/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Can you paste the entire `gem install` output? It should mention the library it failed to compile against.

Comment: are u sure about the version of your ruby? `Only 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 are supported. For 2.X rubies, consider using byebug.`

Comment: I included the `bundle update` and `gem install` outputs. And yes it is 1.9.3

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work. The error came up because of the RubyGems version. `ruby 1.9.3` seems to have incompatibilities with RubyGems above 1.8.x. To resolve this issue, just downgrade to RubyGems 1.8.29: `gem update --system 1.8.29`.